# TSQL - Get additional data from groupped result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have problem to create sql query.
I have one table, which contains columns & data:

Id COL1 COL2  COL3  COL4 COL5 COL6 COL7 
1 FGA  DSA  2018-01-01 DB1 7999  1   0
2 FGA  DSA  2018-01-01 DB1 6999  0   0
3 FGA  DSA  2018-01-01 DB2 5999  1   1

I have a query:

```
SELECT t.COL3, t.COL1, t.COL2, STRING_AGG (c.COL4, ','), min(c.COL5)
FROM Offers as t
JOIN Offers as c on t.Id = c.Id
where t.COL3 between '2017-12-01' and '2017-12-31'
and t.COL1='FGA'
GROUP BY t.COL3, t.COL1, t.COL2
```

But for STRING_AGG (c.COL4, ',') I need distinct values and for min(c.COL5) i need to condition 'where COL6 = 1'. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STRING_AGG()` doesn't (yet) support `DISTINCT`.  You can do what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.COL3, t.COL1, t.COL2,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN c.COL4 END, ','), 
       MIN(CASE WHEN c.col6 = 1 THEN c.COL5 END)
FROM (SELECT t.COL1, t.COL2, t.COL3, c.COL4, c.COL5, c.col6,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.COL3, t.COL1, t.COL2, t.COL4 ORDER BY c.COL4) as seqnum
      FROM Offers t JOIN
           Offers c 
           ON t.Id = c.Id
      WHERE t.GenerationId = 1 AND
            t.COL3 between '2017-12-01' and '2017-12-31' AND
            t.COL1 = 'FGA'
      GROUP BY t.COL3, t.COL1, t.COL2
     ) to
GROUP BY t.COL3, t.COL1, t.COL2;
```

Note the use of `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the first value of `COL4`, which is then used for the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Not exactly working, but with this hint I managed this. Thanks!